# Confused About Limit Points and Closed Sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

According to Rudin,

> A point $p$ is a limit point of a set $E$ $\subseteq X$ (where $X$ is a metric space) if every neighborhood of $p$, $N_r (p)$, contains a point $q \ne p$, such that $q \in E$.
>
> $E$ is a closed set iff all limit points of $E$ are points in $E$.

But how can closed sets exist? For any interval (other than intervals like $\mathbb{R}$), say $I = [x,y]$, can't I take some point $k$ not necessarily in $I$ and make $r$ big enough that $N_r (k)$ contains at least one point in $I$?

For example, consider $I = [0, 1]$. Can't I take $5$, which is clearly not in $I$, but make $r$ something like $4.5$? Then, $N_{4.5} (5)$ would be $[5 - 4.5, 5 + 4.5]$ which clearly contains some points in [$0, 1$]. In this case, wouldn't $5$ be a limit point that's not in $I$ (since I can make any neighborhood of $5$ with $r$ big enough to intersect $I$)? If so, can't be done for really any interval? So, how can closed sets exist? Clearly, there's something I'm not getting, because closed sets *do* exist. Any clarifications/help with intuition would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Ohhh, I think I just got it. I was thinking of one specific case, but EVERY neighborhood of $p$ needs to contain elements of $E$. So, if $r$ is infinitely small, $5$ clearly cannot be a limit point. I can't believe I missed that. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment is correct. This statement is a little vague, but when it says "every interval" it means "for every $r$."